# Cannot find Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in VS15 it is working fine in VS10

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, office-interop

I am using MSWord api, problem is that when i compile the code with Visual Studio 2010 and run the binaries on VM (Where Visual Studio tools for office are not installed) with Microsoft Office 2010 installed, it works just fine. But when I compile the same code on VS15 it doesn't work on same VM. 
This the error that I keep getting,

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So, can someone please explain where is the problem.

FYI, when I place Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll on VM it works fine, but in case of VS2010 compiled code there is no need to copy this file.

Comment: Install it again via nuget on VS15?

Comment: Did that but same result.